# How I getting the address?

Tags: php, symfony

I explain my problem: I display ads on a page, today I only display them but I would like to make a system a little airbnb by adding a map and make sure that my ads are displayed with markers on the map. I would like to convert all the addresses of my ads in longness & attitude to be able to integrate them to the Google map except that in my controller I can not get the address of the ad.

I think very seriously that it is an idiotic problem, however, I do research unfortunately I can not find the solution.

**What I do**
Here is some of my controller to display my ads.

```
public function listAction(Request $request, $companies)
{
    $listCompanies = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Advert::class)->getCompaniesHavingAdverts();

    $listName = array();
    foreach($listCompanies as $company){
        array_push($listName, $company["nameCompany"]);
    }

    if($companies){
        $adverts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Advert::class)->filterAdvertsByCompanyName($companies);
    }else{
        $adverts = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Advert::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $adverts,
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        12 // LIMITE D'ANNONCE PAR PAGE
    );

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)

        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('jobcategory', JobCategoryType::class,
            ['required' => false,
                'placeholder' => "Catégorie ",
                'attr'     => ['class' => 'form-control']])
        ->add('city', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Code Postal : *',
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => "Ex : 75013 Paris, France"],
        ])
        ->add('company', ChoiceType::class,[
            'label' => 'Nom entreprise :',
            'placeholder' => "Nom entreprise ",
            'choices' => $listName,
            'choice_label' => function($company){
                return $company;
            },
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => "Equipier ..."],
        ])
        ->add('Filtrer', SubmitType::class,
            ['attr'     => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block', 'style' => "width: 120px;"]])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted()){
        $filter = $form->getdata();
        $ville = explode(",",$filter['city'])[0];
        $num = array_search($filter["company"],$listName);

        if($filter['company'] == null){
            $listCompanies[$num]["id"] = false;
        }

        $adverts = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Advert::class)
            ->filterAdverts($ville, $filter['jobcategory'],$listCompanies[$num]["id"]);



        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $adverts,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            12// LIMITE D'ANNONCE PAR PAGE
        );
    }

    $adresseAdvert = $adverts->getPostalCode();
    $formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(',','+',$adresseAdvert);
    $formattedAddrFrom = urlencode($formattedAddrFrom);
    $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false&key=');
    $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
    $latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

     return $this->render('App/Student/adverts.html.twig', [
        'adverts' => $pagination,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'pagination' => $pagination,
         'lat' => $latitudeFrom,
         'lng' => $longitudeFrom
    ]);
}
```

**What I want**
Where it crashes, it is during the recovery the address of the ad "$ addressAdvert = $adverts->getPostalCode();" it puts me that we can not get a table (which I totally understand because he does not know which address from which ad).

I do not know how.
In the view to display the ads I have a {% for advert in adverts%} and then I display the ads with cards ..

Answer (score 1):

## Unknown table 'a' ?

From what I understand you're getting an error similar to "cannot get table"?
That sounds to me like a database-related error. Have you verified that all of your database interactions are successful?

(You can print information to the output with `var_export($variable);` to inspect it in your browser. Not ideal, but it could help.)

On line 16, you write `->createQueryBuilder('a')`, this seems suspicious to me. Are you sure the 'a' is meant to be that, or should you pass the table name here?

## Pagination

On several places, you write

```
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $adverts, 
    /* page number */, 
    /* items per page */
);
```

`$adverts` seems to be a list of advertisements (hence the name).

It seems to me that this `paginate()` function returns the relevant section of your list of advertisements; `$adverts`. Perhaps you should be using `$pagination` instead of `$adverts` in the remaining part of this function/method.

Unless I misunderstood what `paginate()` does, but as you did not include any of the called functions in your question, I can't do better than make an educated guess.

## Accessing a member function from an array instead of its elements.

Another suspicious line of code is line 80, where you mention your code fails:

```
$adresseAdvert = $adverts->getPostalCode();
```

Are you sure this is correct? It seems to me you are trying to access a postal code from a single address, while `$adverts` is plural. Perhaps this should be:

```
$adresseAdvert = $adverts[0]->getPostalCode(); // index 0 of array $adverts
```